# Amazon S3 contains a file that cannot be found in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket in AWS, and I have tried to list all the files in the bucket by:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-1 --recursive | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort > bucket_1_files
```

This works for most files, but there are some files that are listed in bucket_1_files, but when I search for the file in the Amazon S3 bucket in the console, I cannot find the files (no matches returned when I search for the name) - would anyone know of possible reasons this could be the case? The file is a .png file, and there are other .png files listed that I can find within the console.

Comment: Question is not clear. first you mentioned that you are not able to find in console and in the end you mentioned you are able to find in console

Comment: there is a specific file called arizona.png that is listed in bucket_1_files, but I can't find it in the console. However, there are other png files listed which I can find.

Comment: Yes, your `sed` seems to be doing something sinister with `t` characters. Try: `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-1 | cut -c 32-`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the command I'm using, when I just do

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-1 --recursive
```

I am finding that a lot of these missing files actually have a "t" in front of them

Answer (score 0):

Rather than playing with aws, sed and sort, you can list objects with:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-1 --query 'Contents[].[Key]' --output text
```

However, it will only return 1000 objects.

Comment: I have more than 1000 objects, but thanks anyhow